# VB.NET Referenciar TextBox de un Form a otro Form

Tags: vb.net

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clase VistaMenu
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class FrmGestionUsuarios

        Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario
        Private _modelUsuario As New ModelUsuario.ModelUsuario
        Private f As New VistaUsuarios.FrmAddUsuario
        Private msj_alert As String

        Public Sub New()
            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()

            ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
            If _controllerUsuario.RutaGetUsuario(msj_alert) IsNot Nothing AndAlso _controllerUsuario.RutaGetUsuario(msj_alert).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                DGVusuarios.DataSource = _controllerUsuario.RutaGetUsuario(msj_alert)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(msj_alert, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub FrmGestionUsuarios_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub

        Private Sub BtnAgregarUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregarUsuario.Click

            f.ShowDialog()



        End Sub

        Private Sub DGVusuarios_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVusuarios.CellDoubleClick



            End If
        End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class FrmAddUsuario

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmAddUsuario_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

trato de referenciar un textbox que se encuentra en el segundo form de esta manera f.textbox1.text pero al parecer no es posible referenciarlo de esa forma

Comment: La otra era usar un InputBox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es incorrecto el camino que estas tomando, no deberias referenciar ningun control de forma directa desde un form en otro, sino que deberias exponer propiedades o metodos publicos que devuelvan el dato o realicen alguna accion en el form.

En el FrmAddUsuario, podrias exponer una propiedad como ser

```
Public Class FrmAddUsuario

    'resto codigo

    Public Property TextBox1Prop() As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            TextBox1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Entonces si desde el FrmGestionUsuarios vas a poder acceder al valor del control por medio de la propiedad

```
Private Sub BtnAgregarUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregarUsuario.Click

    f.ShowDialog()

    Dim textbox1Usuario As String = f.TextBox1Prop

End Sub
```

En resumen usas las capacidades orientadas a objetos de .net y trabaja con propiedades, metodo y eventos encapsulando la funcionalidad

Comment: Gracias funciona a la perfección!